# how to run scala .jar with external jar files in terminal

Tags: scala, terminal, jar, sbt

I have my .jar built from scala classes and it has an external dependency with other.jar. Please suggest how should I run my jar files in terminal. The command I tried is

> $scala my_scala.jar external.jar

Answer (score 1):

It works same way as running java program. Try this

```
scala -classpath <your_scala_jar>:<external_jar> <package.MainClass>
```